# No shading in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, options

Say you want to plot a horizontal plane using

```
ContourPlot3D[x == 0, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {z, 0, 100}]
```

How to turn off the **shading**? I would like to have only a transparent grid. The option `ContourShading` seems not to be the correct parameter to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `ContourStyle`:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 ContourStyle -> None
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]